# How do I show hidden files just for some directories?

Tags: filemanager, hidden-files

Are you aware of any file manager that is able to remember whether you want to show or hide hidden files for a specific directory?
I.e. i never want to see hidden files in my home, but i would like to see them in all the other directories.

Thanks.

Comment: Some file managers have the option to remember settings per folder. In *Dolphin*, I can do what you want. I'm sure other file managers allow that as well.

Answer (score 0):

The [Nautilus](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-hidden.html.en) file manager for Ubuntu is capable of doing this on a per-folder basis:

> If you want to see all hidden files in a folder, go to that folder and either click the view options button in the toolbar and pick Show Hidden Files, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. You will see all hidden files, along with regular files that are not hidden.

Comment: I'm not sure whether recent versions of Nautilus have this feature (per-folder basis).